# Short story about humans captured by aliens, kept as pets

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens

I read this short story years ago so the details are hazy but it is about an alien who is talking to someone else (presumably another alien) about his pet.  All this time it is assumed that the aliens are people and the pet is an alien.  Then at the end you finally "see" the pet in the cage and realize that the captured one, the pet, was the human all along.  I believe it is a fairly short story and it can't be newer than 10 years since I believe I read it about ten years ago.

Comment: I don't think your story is there, but https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/HumanPet may be relevant (warning, TV Tropes link).

Comment: Maybe "Youth", an Asimov short story?

Comment: It is "Youth" thank you!

Comment: Glad to help! As this is a duplicate of another answer, it will be closed as soon as you confirm that "Youth" is correct by clicking on the green check-mark. This is not to say your question is bad though, only that it is a duplicate of another one. Welcome, and I hope you stay around!

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Is the "Warning: TV Tropes" trope explicitly included as a trope in TV Tropes?

Comment: @Lexible: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/JustForFun/TVTropesWillRuinYourLife

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I love you even more now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sounds like "[Youth](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58964)" a short story by Asimov, first published in 1952 and later collected in "The Martian Way and other stories.

The story centers on two children, Red and Slim, who find two alien creatures and keep them secretly as pets, concealing them from their parents. The twist at the end is that we discover that the children are actually the aliens, and the creatures they are keeping are humans.

The full text is available from the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/youth31547gut/pg31547.txt).